# Call and Return function using pointers locally in c

Tags: c, pointers, global-variables, local-variables

Hello there I am learning pointers so I created a calculator.
I managed to return the value and the pointers from a function but by declaring them globally. How can I declare them locally?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
```

Declaration of all functions

```
int Addition();
int Subtraction();
int Devision();
int Multiplication();
```

Declaration of Global Variables, which I would like to declare them locally

```
int p;
int n;
int *r=&n;
int *b=&p;
```

Start of main Function

```
int main()
{
    int g,s;
    while (1)
    {
        printf("Please choose the Arithmetic operation: \n");
        printf("Addition-> 1 \nSubtraction-> 2 \nDevision-> 3 \nMultiplication-> 4 \nExit-> 0\n ");
        scanf("%d",&g);
```

The user chooses  an Arithmetic operation (function) by inputting one number(1,2,3,4 or 0 for Exit)

```
        if  (g==1)
        {
            s=Addition(r,b);
            printf("The addition result is %d+%d=%d",*r, *b, s);
        }
        else if  (g==2)
       {
          s=Subtraction(r,b);
          printf("The Subtraction result is %d-%d=%d",*r, *b, s);
       }

       else if  (g==3)
       {
         s=Devision(r,b);
         printf("The Devision result is %d/%d=%d",*r, *b, s);
       }

       else if  (g==4)
      {
        Multiplication(r,b);
        printf("The Multiplication result is %d/%d=%d",*r, *b, s);
      }
       else
      {
       break;
      }

     return 0;
   }

}
```

End of main function.
Below are all the  other functions

```
Addition()
{
    int x;

    printf("Ennter first nr: ");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    printf("Ennter second nr: ");
    scanf("%d",&p);
    x=n+p;

    return x;
}

Subtraction()
{
    int x;
    printf("Ennter first nr: ");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    printf("Ennter second nr: ");
    scanf("%d",&p);
    x=n-p;
   return x;
}

Devision()
{
    int x;
    printf("Ennter first nr: ");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    printf("Ennter second nr: ");
    scanf("%d",&p);
    x=n / p;
    return x;
}

 Multiplication()
 {
     int x;
     printf("Ennter first nr: ");
     scanf("%d",&n);
     printf("Ennter second nr: ");
     scanf("%d",&p);
     x=n * p;
     return x;
}
```

Comment: Please apply proper indentation to your code to make it more readable.

Comment: And elaborate your question. It is somequat unclear.

Comment: I don't see anything in your code that warrants using global variables.  What makes you think that you need to use them?  It's clear that you already know how to declare and use local (non-global) variables.

Comment: I used them Globally because it was easier for me to call and read them. That is why I want to learn how can I  declare them locally.

Comment: I put the whole code and edited it  hopefully it makes more sense now

Comment: Step one here is to burn your C book/teacher and then re-learn how functions work. Do that before taking on pointers.

Comment: The functions you are describing should be implemented without pointers, for example `double add(double a, double b);`  Usage: `double result = add(45.7, 12.1);`. Implementation: `double add(double, a, double b){ return a + b;}` No pointers required.

Comment: `int Addition();` etc. are illegal declarations and not standard C. Use prototypes. Plus, you have to _define_ variables, not just _declare_ them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Refresh the knowledge about pointers and pass parameters via `pointers` if you want to.

The indirection or dereference operator `*` gives the contents of an object pointed to by a pointer.

The unary or monadic operator `&` gives the address of a variable.

2) Avoid global variables declare them locally after `main`.

3) Use `switch` instead of `if-else` chains

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int Addition(int* n, int* p)
{
    int x;

    printf("Ennter first nr: ");
    scanf("%d",n);
    printf("Ennter second nr: ");
    scanf("%d",p);        
    x = *n + *p;    
    return x;
}

int Subtraction(int* n, int* p)
{
    int x;

    printf("Ennter first nr: ");
    scanf("%d",n);
    printf("Ennter second nr: ");
    scanf("%d",p);
    x = *n  - *p;  
    return x;
}

int main(void)
{  
    int n1 = 0;
    int n2 = 0;
    int *r = &n1;
    int *b = &n2;   
    int g,s;

    while (1)
    {
        printf("Please choose the Arithmetic operation: \n");
        printf("Addition-> 1 \nSubtraction-> 2 \nDevision-> 3 \nMultiplication-> 4 \nExit-> 0\n ");
        scanf("%d",&g);

        switch(g)
        {
            case 0:
               printf("END\n");
               return 0;
            break;                
            case 1:
                s = Addition(r, b);
                printf("The addition result is: %d+%d=%d\n\n",n1, n2, s);
                break;
            case 2:
                s = Subtraction(r ,b);
                printf("The Subtraction result is: %d-%d=%d\n\n",*r, *b, s);
            break;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Test:

```
Please choose the Arithmetic operation:                                                                                                         
Addition-> 1                                                                                                                                    
Subtraction-> 2                                                                                                                                 
Devision-> 3                                                                                                                                    
Multiplication-> 4                                                                                                                              
Exit-> 0                                                                                                                                        
 2                                                                                                                                              
Ennter first nr: 5                                                                                                                              
Ennter second nr: 3                                                                                                                             
The Subtraction result is: 5-3=2                                                                                                                

Please choose the Arithmetic operation:                                                                                                         
Addition-> 1                                                                                                                                    
Subtraction-> 2                                                                                                                                 
Devision-> 3                                                                                                                                    
Multiplication-> 4                                                                                                                              
Exit-> 0                                                                                                                                        
 0                                                                                                                                              
END
```

Comment: thanks for the code. It really helped me understand how to call and read pointers and variables from functions.
I am still in the process of learning the pointers and  I see a lot of people insulting and pointing me out. Nevertheless, I don't care !

Comment: @KlaydPro I am glad that I could help you. Keep learning. Never give up.

Answer (score 0):

*I used them Globally because it was easier for me to call and read them. That is why I want to learn how can I declare them locally.*

Very simply, just declare them locally, as shown: (without your user input code to focus on your primary question)

```
int main(void)
{   // locally declared
   double a = 4.5;
   double b = 10.8;

   double result_1, result_2, result_3, result_4;

   result_1 = add(a, b);       
   result_2 = sub(a, b);       
   result_3 = mul(a, b);       
   result_4 = div(a, b);


   return 0;
}

// example function (the others will be of similar form,
// a single return line with the appropriate math operator.

double add(double a, double b)//no pointers necessary
{
    return a + b;
}
```

If you *really* want to use a pointer, then you can implement the function to return the result via an argument:

```
void add(double a, double b, double *result)
{
    *result = a + b;
}
```

Usage: (call from main for example)

```
   add(a, b, &result_1);// passing the address of result_1      
                        // to allow the value at that address
                        // to be modified.
```

Answer (score -1):

Well, not sure if this is what you are asking for, but let me suggest you this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int Addition(int* n, int* p)
{
    int x;

    printf("Ennter first nr: ");
    scanf("%d",n);
    printf("Ennter second nr: ");
    scanf("%d",p);
    x=*n+*p;

    return x;
}

int main()
{
    int n1=0;
    int n2=0;
    int *r=&n1;
    int *b=&n2;

    int g,s;

    while (1)
    {
        printf("Please choose the Arithmetic operation: \n");
        printf("Addition-> 1 \nSubtraction-> 2 \nDevision-> 3 \nMultiplication-> 4 \nExit-> 0\n ");
        scanf("%d",&g);

        if  (g==1)
        {
            s=Addition(r,b);
            printf("The addition result is %d+%d=%d",*r, *b, s);
        }

        return 0;
    }
}
```

As you can see, we are using pointers to store the value of the number written by the user, so you can keep them after calling the function.

Comment: Not really because you still got your variables globally. My intention is to have them declared locally by using the pointers also locally

Comment: Oh, sorry, I made the changes so it worked with local variables, but did not move them. I have edited this post, so they are now local variables (inside your main function)